# Multiple Angular Project hosting on a single Firebase project

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting, portfolio

I am looking into hosting a portfolio site with multiple Angular projects under a single Firebase project(eg https://aaaaa.firebaseapp.com/) . So say I have 3 angular apps (abc ,def and ghi). I will be displaying them on a single portfolio landing page and host on firebase.
eg https://aaaaa.firebaseapp.com/abc
                 https://aaaaa.firebaseapp.com/def
                 https://aaaaa.firebaseapp.com/ghi
How can this be done or is it even possible? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting supports having multiple sites per project. You can then configure each site to be served under a path.

```
{
  "hosting": [ {
      "target": "blog",  // "blog" is the applied target name for the Hosting site "myapp-blog"
      "public": "blog/dist",  // contents of this folder are deployed to the site "myapp-blog"

      // ...
    },
    {
      "target": "app",  // "app" is the applied target name for the Hosting site "myapp-app"
      "public": "app/dist",  // contents of this folder are deployed to the site "myapp-app"

      // ...

      "rewrites": [...]  // You can define specific Hosting configurations for each site
    }
  ]
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#define_hosting_config