# Multiple Firebase Project in same Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-console

I dont know how configure my angular app so that handle multiple firebase project

I am currently working on 3 different angular applications to which a firebase project is attached, so I am thinking about how to create an angular application that groups my three firebase projects inside.

Comment: You can modify environment prod and use key's of those project.

Answer (score 0):

We can use multiple Firebase projects which include:

- Setting up your development environment to use different Firebase
  projects based on build type or target.
- Accessing the content from multiple Firebase projects in your app.

Refer to this [Link1](https://medium.com/@handersonc/connecting-angular-with-multiple-firebase-projects-889bb7de1f56) , [Link2](https://alexmammay.medium.com/multiple-firebase-projects-in-one-angular-app-1b845b4d5322#:%7E:text=First%20we%20are%20going%20to,want%20to%20use%20in%20firebase.) , and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305936/multiple-angular-project-hosting-on-a-single-firebase-project) and watch this reference [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mn5O2d14cdY) for how to set the multiple Firebase Project in same Angular app